# Given a vector of maximum 10 000 natural and distinct numbers, find 4 numbers(a, b, c, d) such that a + b + c = d

Tags: algorithm, math

I solved this problem by following a straightforward but not optimal algorithm. I sorted the vector in descending order and after that substracted numbers from max to min to see if I get a + b + c = d.
Notice that I haven't used anywhere the fact that elements are natural, distinct and 10 000 at most. I suppose these details are the key.
Does anyone here have a hint over an optimal way of solving this?

Thank you in advance!

Later Edit:
My idea goes like this:

```
'<<quicksort in descending order>>'

for i:=0 to count { // after sorting, loop through the array
    int d := v[i];
    for j:=i+1 to count {
        int dif1 := d - v[j];
        int a := v[j];

       for k:=j+1 to count {
           if (v[k] > dif1)
              continue;
           int dif2 := dif1 - v[k];
         b := v[k];

    for l:=k+1 to count {
 if (dif2 = v[l]) {
    c := dif2; 
     return {a, b, c, d}
 }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think?(sorry for the bad indentation)

Comment: Does `a, b, c, d` have to be different numbers, or can you use the same number several times?

Comment: If the numbers are natural (i.e., they run from zero to infinity), you first discard all the numbers greater than `d`.

Comment: look much like projecteuler.net ;) (where it is kind of forbidden asking those things)

Comment: Don't know what projecteuler.net is. I'll take a look though.

Answer (score 7):

Solution in O(n<sup>2</sup> log n):

Compute sets of all possible sums and differences:

{a<sub>i</sub>+a<sub>j</sub>: 1 <= i,j <= n}

{a<sub>i</sub>-a<sub>j</sub>: 1 <= i,j <= n}

(store them in a balanced binary search tree) and check if they have a common element. If yes, there are i,j,k,l such that a<sub>i</sub> + a<sub>j</sub> = a<sub>k</sub> - a<sub>l</sub>, that is a<sub>i</sub>+a<sub>j</sub>+a<sub>l</sub>=a<sub>k</sub>.

Solution in O(a<sub>n</sub> log a<sub>n</sub>), where a<sub>n</sub> is the largest number in the vector:

Compute the polynomial

(x<sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>+x<sup>a<sub>2</sub></sup> + ... + x<sup>a<sub>n</sub></sup>)<sup>3</sup>

you can do it in O(a<sub>n</sub> log a<sub>n</sub>) using [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) (first compute square, then third power; see [here](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/polymultiply.pdf) for description). Observe that after multiplication a coefficient x<sup>b<sub>i</sub></sup> was formed from multiplication x<sup>a<sub>i</sub></sup> * x<sup>a<sub>j</sub></sup> * x<sup>a<sub>k</sub></sup>= x<sup>a<sub>i</sub>+a<sub>j</sub>+a<sub>k</sub></sup> for some i,j,k. Check if there is a power x<sup>a<sub>l</sub></sup> in the resulting polynomial.

Unfortunately this allows some i,j,k to be used twice. Subtracting 3(x<sup>2a<sub>1</sub></sup>+...+x<sup>2a<sub>n</sub></sup>)*(x<sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup>+...+x<sup>a<sub>n</sub></sup>) - 2(x<sup>3a<sub>1</sub></sup>+...+x<sup>3a<sub>n</sub></sup>) will remove those x<sup>a<sub>i</sub>+a<sub>j</sub>+a<sub>k</sub></sup>.

Comment: I was about to post your BST solution, but with hashtable instead. If `a < b < c < d` is a restriction, then you have to do something extra, because right now you're allowing some numbers to appear twice.

Comment: You can tag the elements in the two trees with indices of elements: {(a_i+a_j, i, j): 1 <= i,j <= n} and {(a_i-a_j, i, j): 1 <= i,j <= n}; when joining the lists, check if the tags are all different.

Comment: If using a hashtable instead of the tree, you could get rid of O(log n) by using the sum/difference as key. After having computed and inserted all (a+b)-sums, you would just have to check for the differences if there is an element -(d-c) in the (a+b) table. That gives a total runtime of O(n^2).

Comment: Assuming you can create a bit array with 2*a_n elements initialized to zero. If not, this solution is O(a_n + n^2).

Comment: If you use tuples such as (a+b,a,b) for your sums and (b-a,a,b) for your differences, where a < b, in the hashtable as the keys, then you have enforced the `a < b < c < d` restriction.

Comment: This is most likely a 3SUM-Hard problem. In other words, don't look for better than O(N^2) solutions :-)

Comment: @MicSim: your algorithm in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973418/given-a-vector-of-maximum-10-000-natural-and-distinct-numbers-find-4-numbersa/2979763#2979763

Answer (score 4):

There is an algorithm by Shamir and Schroeppel that solves this problem in time O(N^2) and with memory O(N), when N is the number of inputs. It basically is what sdcvvc proposes, but instead of storing the sets {a<sub>i</sub> + a<sub>j</sub>} as a whole one would repeatedly compute only the sums in appropriate intervals. This saves memory, but does not increase the time complexity.

Richard Schroeppel, Adi Shamir: "A T=O(2^(n/2)), S=O(2^(n/4)) Algorithm for Certain NP-Complete Problems". SIAM J. Comput. 10(3): 456-464 (1981)

Comment: related "A 2010 Algorithm for the Knapsack Problem" http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/a-2010-algorithm-for-the-knapsack-problem/

Answer (score 1):

Here's [@MicSim's comment to @sdcvvc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973418/given-a-vector-of-maximum-10-000-natural-and-distinct-numbers-find-4-numbersa/2973712#2973712) implemented in Python:

```
def abcd(nums):
    sums = dict((a+b, (a,b)) for a, b in combinations(nums, 2))

    for c, d in combinations(sorted(nums), 2): # c < d
        if (d-c) in sums:
            a, b = sums[d-c]
            assert (a+b+c) == d
            if a == c or b == c: continue # all a,b,c,d must be different
            a,b,c = sorted((a,b,c))
            assert a < b < c < d
            return a,b,c,d
```

Where `combinations()` could be [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) or

```
def combinations(arr, r):
    assert r == 2 # generate all unordered pairs
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        for j in xrange(i+1, len(arr)):
            yield v, arr[j]
```

It is O(N<sup>2</sup>) in time and space.

Example:

```
>>> abcd(range(1, 10000))
(1, 2, 3, 6)
```

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan: `combinations()` produces `N*(N-1)/2` pairs therefore `sums` takes O(N**2) memory and O(N**2) time to create it, and there are O(N**2) (c,d) pairs to process. `(d-c) in sums` is assumed to be O(1) therefore the whole (c,d)-loop is O(N**2) in time.